# How to do ActiveModel out of box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

Ok, I was poking around github's rails activemodel stuff for the heck of it.

Link: https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activemodel

When I saw this code included in their README.rdoc

```
 class Person
    include ActiveModel::AttributeMethods

    attribute_method_prefix 'clear_'
    define_attribute_methods :name, :age

    attr_accessor :name, :age

    def clear_attribute(attr)
        send("#{attr}=", nil)
    end
  end

  person = Person.new

  person.clear_name

  person.clear_age
```

Thought that above code was pretty cool as I wasn't familiar with this. Only have seen something like this with dynamic find method, sort of.

So wanted to run it, but I don't know how to run it outside of the context of ROR framework.

How do I go about doing that?

Thanks.

If this question is dumb, let me know? (nicely, please).

Asking because I've heard that people run ORM outside of ROR framework, so, that's why I'm asking this question in the first place. Let me know if I misunderstood this.

Answer (score 0):

You could always run it in an IRB as it's a ruby method not specific to Rails.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-sendirb

Answer (score 0):

For doing Active Record Like Models you could use this gem http://rubygems.org/gems/activemodel, or this gem https://github.com/solnic/virtus.

Answer (score 0):

First create one dummy application in Rails,then open rails console using this command `rails c` and you past the code then you could verify.

or

Inside application lib directory create one file with `.rb` extension now open console and you can verify.

More info [click here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)